# Best practice for tempdb log file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, tempdb

I have read many blogs here and there about how to configure tempdb data files but i didnt found any information regarding the **tempdb log file**.

Here's the strategy that I'm presently using with my tempdb:

- I have used the [recommendations of Paul Randal](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-1230-tempdb-should-always-have-one-data-file-per-processor-core/) on how to split my tempdb data files
- I have set the size of my tempdb data files to their maximum and disabled autogrowth. For example, i have 100gb of free disk space and set the size of my 8 tempdb data files to 10gb each. This prevent fragmentation on the disk as [recommended by Brent Ozar](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2008/03/sql-server-2005-setup-checklist-part-1-before-the-install/) and also I have 20gb free for my log file.

But like I said, nobody is talking about the **tempdb log file**. What should I do with it? On my setup, this file is at the same place as the tempdb data files. What is the size and the autogrowth value that I should use with the tempdb log file?

Comment: There is no magic answer for this, except that I would *not* disable autogrowth for tempdb data or log unless you absolutely want the system to come to a screeching halt should autogrow be needed. I would never disable autogrow on any file, because no matter how well you plan, there are always abnormal situations.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: enable autogrowth on a full sized tempdb will not help. They are already at their maximum they can be on the drive. There's no more disk space that they can use anyway. This is why i have disabled the autogrowth.

Comment: Then it doesn't matter if it's disabled or not, does it? If an autogrow is required, it's going to fail either way. If you leave it enabled, that's one less thing you have to change when you realize that maybe you need to move it to a bigger drive.

Comment: P.S. 8 x 20 > 100

Comment: you're right. I guest i should leave it on. I have corrected a few flaws in my text too :)

Comment: Also have you done any performance testing of this config? I'd be surprised if you got substantial benefits out of 8 data files on the same drive (with or without the log file on the same drive too) compared to 1, 2, or 4. There is a little there but you're still bound by the capabilities of that single drive. How did you determine, exactly, that multiple tempdb files would help you?

Comment: i havent done any performance testing. I just wanted to start with a good setup and i took what others gurus are recommending for that. It's like if we are talking about installing SQL Server on a single drive vs seperate drives for the UserData, SystemData and tempdb. I'm pretty sure that i will not see a difference for the firsts months but in the long term, it's clear that it is better to have a disk strategy. So this is why i was asking about ideas on how to configure tempdb log data.

Comment: Splitting your files isn't necessarily "a good setup". It depends on your hardware configuration; which you have not supplied.

Comment: "I havent done any performance testing." Then you need to do some. Every performance technique you read is going to come with a "your mileage may vary" disclaimer because everyone's workloads are different. That said, to answer the question - use one file for the log, placed on its own disk array if you have the ability to do so. SQL Server treats multiple log files as if they were one sequential stream, so there is no point in having multiple files unless the disk is full (from Inside SQL Server 2005, pp 156-157, I don't have the later books at hand).

Answer (score 5):

It really depends on how much data is going to flow through the transaction log.  Look at how big the log gets today.  You need to configure the log to be at least that size when SQL starts up.  For most of my clients they end up with a 3-4 Gig transaction log for the tempdb, which contains just a few VLFs and everything works nice and smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I was always told to store log files on a separate physical/disk array if your hardware can write simultaneously to data and log at the same time to improve performance. I would guess the limitation that spawned your 20G tempdb limit might define an answer for size. For autogrowth, that might depend on the transactions you are running as well as free space available and other resources on disk. I typically pick 1/6th of the initial size arbitrarily.

Answer (score 0):

Aaron is right configuring TempDB is dependent on lot of variables such as whether or not you plan on using snapshot isolation etc. Here is a older [SQL 2005 white paper from MS/TN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966545.aspx) that might help you out since a good bit of it still applies. Specifically have a look at the "Space required for tempdb logging" so you can see what kinds transactions are logged in the tempdb log so you can set things up accordingly. It is likely going to be the sort of thing that you will have to monitor and tweak over time.

As far as authogrowth for tempdb I have reluctantly disabled this on a reporting server in the past and the behavior I have experienced was that it caused the long running transaction to abort and roll back which instantly freed up the log space but that might depend on the type of transaction which in my case is was massive sorts and join operations (poorly written report queries). I agree with Aaron and would recommend avoiding this if possible especially in high transaction volume situations.